# Ucfirst Returing Incorrect Result

Tags: php, capitalize

In my code i have a string and i want to capitalize first letter of each word using php function.

This is my code:

```
$str = "144 beach st,daytona beach,FL,32114";
echo ucfirst($str);
```

It displays the same result:

```
144 beach st,daytona beach,FL,32114
```

So how can i capitalize the word?If there is any mistake in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`ucwords`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) instead to capitialize first letter of each word.

```
$str = "144 beach st, daytona beach, FL, 32114";
echo ucwords($str);
```

**Result:**

```
144 Beach St, Daytona Beach, FL, 32114
```

Comment: But why dont capitalize the word "daytona"

Comment: @KichuUser: Because of incorrect punctuation rules, put an space before that word and then that will also be capitalized example: `$str = "144 beach st, daytona beach, FL, 32114";`. Answer also updated, hope that helps.